# How to append a input inside an anchor tag using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, tags, anchor

please help, I got the anchor tag with a span inside, Using Jquery how do i append an input without losing the span and using the actual value!??

I got this

```
<a class='fieldEditable' href='#'><span class='blue'>Id. Usuario</span> **Juan David**</a>
```

I want to use the value Juan David as value of an input

```
<a class='fieldEditable' href='#'><span class='blue'>Id. Usuario</span><input type="text" name="newid" value="**Juan David**"> </a>
```

the span class='blue' Is not the same in some cases i mean it changes

i tried

```
$('a.fieldEditable').append('<input type="text" name="newid" value="">');
```

Result

```
<a class='fieldEditable' href='#'><span class='blue'>Id. Usuario</span> **Juan David**<input type="text" name="newid" value="**HOW MOVE THE VALUE JUAN DAVID TO HERE??**"></a>
```

It's almost done I need some help !!!

Comment: no just an error trying to make it in bold style !! the value always be a name in this case Juan David

Comment: You want the `<input>` *inside* the `<a>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Targeting textNodes is a bit difficult, but here's one approach:

```js
$(".fieldEditable")
    .contents()
    .filter(textNodes)
    .each(function(index, object){
        $("<input>", { 
            type: "text", 
            value: object.textContent.trim() 
        }).replaceAll(this).before(" ");
    });

function textNodes () {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.textContent.trim().length;
}​
```

```html
<a class='fieldEditable' href='#'>
    <span class='blue'>Id. Usuario</span> 
    Juan David
</a>​
```

Which results in the following:

```html
<a class="fieldEditable" href="#">
    <span class="blue">Id. Usuario</span> 
    <input type="text" value="Juan David">
</a>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TxvYE/

Answer (score 1):

You can change the markup:

```
<a class='fieldEditable' href='#'><span class='blue'>Id. Usuario</span><span id='target'>**Juan David**</span></a>
```

And js:

```
$('a.fieldEditable').append('<input type="text" name="newid" value="">');
$('input[name=newid]').val($('#target').text());
```

Comment: $('a.fieldEditable').live('click',function(){
    $('a.fieldEditable').append('<input type="text" name="newid" value="">');
    $('input[name=newid]').val($('#target').text())
    $('#target').remove();
  });

Comment: What happens? Value is not changing or what?

Comment: I wanna append the input use the value Juan David inside the input and removing from <a> yeah is like simulating a field edit you click it it lets you modify and thats all

Comment: ok !! sorry was a problem with the markup thanks so much Maxim Pechenin

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var v=$('a.fieldEditable').html();
var newHTML=v+'<input type="text" name="newid" value="">';
$('a.fieldEditable').html(newHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a container

```
<a class='fieldEditable' href='#'><span class='blue'>Id. Usuario</span><span id='target'>**Juan David**</span></a>
```

And then its easy to replace :

```
var target = $('#target');
target.replaceWith($('<input/>').val(target.text())
```

Comment: yeah Just what i was looking for thanks Gaurav Shah it worked pretty well

Comment: You should upvote an answer when you find it good and you should accept an answer if it right for your question or solves you problem - The way SO Community works

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your markup - and using a javascript regex you can use this:

```
var inner = $('.fieldEditable').html();
var re = /(<span.*<\/span>) ([\s\S]+)/i;
var m = re.exec(inner);
if(m != null && m.length == 3) {
    var span = m[1];
    var person = m[2]
    $('.fieldEditable').html(span + '<input type="text" name="newid" value="' + person + '">')
}
```